# Xamarin.iOS - Client.PairedDevices does not return the devices

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, 32feet

I am using this 32feet Library (InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth - Bluetooth Classic NuGet package)  to get a list of paired devices In my Xamarin.Forms app. I can get a device list in Android but not in iOS.
when I call to BluetoothClient.PairedDevices, it returns values when on Android, but on iOS it's always empty.

Does this library have support for iOS or is there any mistake in the code, does we have to add any configuration in info.plist file?

I am attaching the code for reference(which is in C#).

**BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient(); foreach (var device in client.PairedDevices) { GeolocationDevices.Add(device.DeviceName); }**

Here, is the permission I allow in info.plist file
[Info.Plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKP1v.png)

Can anyone suggest me an idea if I am missing anything regarding provisioning profiles, info.plist permissions etc.

Thanks in advance.